# How to return additions of numbers that are divisible from certain numbers in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, math

So I'm creating a function that should return the addition of all the numbers that are smaller and equal to x that are divisible by 4 or 5, but should not add the numbers that are divisible by both of them at the same time. So far I have been able to code in the function that is able to take numbers divisible 4 and 5 and return it. However I haven't been able to code for the ability to add numbers that are divisible by both. The picture below should display what I want python to output.

[image]

Heres the code so far on what I've worked on:

```
def personal_numbers(num):
    #variable to store the sum
    sum=0
    #running loop through the range
    #if a number is divisible by i 
    for i in range(1000):
        if (i%4==0 and i%5==0):
            sum+=i
        return sum
print(personal_numbers(12))
```

Comment: Do not use `sum` as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Two things. Don't use sum as a variable, you will get `Nonetype` when using `sum([x,y])`. Lastly, you have a return in your for loop. This will stop the program at the very first iteration.

```
def personal_numbers(num):
    #variable to store the sum
    sum=0
    #running loop through the range
    #if a number is divisible by i 
    for i in range(1000):
        if (i%4==0 and i%5==0):
            sum+=i
    return sum
print(personal_numbers(12))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Several points**:

- Please, **Never** use *build-in* function as variable name. A common workaround is to prefixe variables with `_`: `sum_`.
- You don't take `num` variable into account. You should iterate until this `num` values so the *for loop* becomes:

```
for i in range(num + 1):
```

- The `if` statement isn't fully correct, you also need to exclude numbers that are both divisible by `4` and `5`. So simply check `i%4 != i%5`:

```
if (i % 4 == 0 or i%5==0) and i%4 != i%5:
```

- The return statement must be outside the *for loop*.

**Code**:

```
def personal_numbers(num):
     sum_=0
     for i in range(num + 1):
          if (i % 4 == 0 or i%5==0) and i%4 != i%5:
               sum_+=i
     return sum_

print(personal_numbers(12))
# 39
print(personal_numbers(21))
# 70
```

---

For fun, you can use *list comprehension* with [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
def personal_numbers_inline(num):
     return sum([i for i in range(num + 1) if (i % 4 == 0 or i%5==0) and i%4 != i%5])
print(personal_numbers_inline(12))
# 39
print(personal_numbers_inline(21))
# 70
```